# What is the difference between "Every. Single. Day." and "Every day"

Tags: differences

I just saw my friend's comment about eating some food stuff that it happens with her

> Every. Single. Day.

That just means *every day*, doesn't it?

Now English isn't my native language. Is this used sarcastically or something like that?

And somewhat help from this I guess. I never knew this as well: [Everyday V Every Day](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/what-is-the-difference-between-everyday-and-every-day)

Comment: It expresses the same finality (and the same vague sense of absurdity about that finality) as "Best. Comment. Ever."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways to emphasize things. One can hyperbolize, repeat, **bold**, underline, put something in italics, draw it out in speech ("Nooooo...!" vs "No."), etc.

> Every. Single. Day.

Each element is isolated and capitalized for emphasis.

Yes, it still means every day, but is much more emphatic. It is also informal, and popular at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of emphasis. Sometimes people say "every day" but actually mean "most days". Your friend wants you to know that she means *every* day.

I don't know what your native language is, but this is similar to how, in Spanish (or any romance language), *yo* (I) and *tú* (you) are unnecessary when used with a verb like *como* (I eat) or *comes* (you eat), because the *I* and *you* are implied. Sometimes you just add the pronoun for emphasis.